# Why Document DB procedure returns only 100 docs on querydocument?

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I have below procedure in Document DB. It executes fine from DocumentDb script explorer but the result it returns is partial. I have more than 250 documents satisfying its given where clause which I checked in query explorer. But when I run procedure from script explorer count(defined in procedure) is always 100.

Below is my procedure -

```
function getInvoice(pageNo, numberOfRecords, member, searchText, customerGroupId,ResellerId) {
var collectionReseller = getContext().getCollection();
var filterquery ;
var count=0, invoiceAmountTotal=0, referalCommissionTotal=0, developerCommissionTotal=0;
var customerIdString='';
var InvoiceList = [];
var whereClause;
if (customerGroupId != "") {
filterquery = 'SELECT c.id from c where c.Type="Customer" and c.CustomerGroupID="' + customerGroupId + '"';
var isAccepted = collectionReseller.queryDocuments(
    collectionReseller.getSelfLink(), filterquery,
    function (err, documents, responseOptions) {
        var docCount = documents.length;
        documents.forEach(function (doc) {
            docCount--;
            if (docCount > 0)
                customerIdString = customerIdString + '"' + doc.id + '", '
            else
                customerIdString = customerIdString + '"' + doc.id + '" '
        })
        whereClause = 'where  r.Type="Invoice" and r.CustomerID IN (' + customerIdString + ')'

        var filterquery1 = 'SELECT * FROM root r  ';
        if (member.length > 0) {

            member.forEach(function (val, i) {
                whereClause = whereClause + ' and contains(r.' + member[i] + ',"' + searchText[i] + '")';
            });
        }
        isAccepted = collectionReseller.queryDocuments(
         collectionReseller.getSelfLink(), filterquery1 + whereClause,
         function (err, invoiceDoc) {
             var qr = filterquery1 + whereClause;
        count = invoiceDoc.length;
             invoiceDoc.forEach(function (doc) {
                 invoiceAmountTotal = parseFloat(invoiceAmountTotal) + parseFloat(doc.InvoiceAmount);
                 referalCommissionTotal = parseFloat(referalCommissionTotal) + parseFloat(doc.ReferralCommission);
                 developerCommissionTotal= parseFloat(developerCommissionTotal) + parseFloat(doc.DeveloperCommission);
                 InvoiceList.push(doc);
             });


             InvoiceList.sort(SortByID);
             InvoiceList = InvoiceList.slice(pageNo * numberOfRecords, pageNo * numberOfRecords + numberOfRecords);
             // Check the feed and if empty, set the body to 'no docs found', 
             // else take 1st element from feed
             getContext().getResponse().setBody(JSON.stringify({ InvoiceList, count, invoiceAmountTotal, referalCommissionTotal, developerCommissionTotal }));

         });
    });
}
else
{   
    whereClause = ' where r.Type = "Invoice" and r.ResellerID = "'+ ResellerId + '"';

    filterquery = 'SELECT * FROM root r ';
    if(member.length > 0) {
    member.forEach(function (val, i) {
        whereClause = whereClause + ' and contains(r.' + member[i] + ',"' + searchText[i] + '")';
    });
}


 filterquery = filterquery + whereClause;

 var isAccepted = collectionReseller.queryDocuments(
    collectionReseller.getSelfLink(), filterquery,
    function (err, documents, responseOptions) {
        if (err) throw err;
        invoiceDoc = documents;
count =invoiceDoc.length;
            invoiceDoc.forEach(function (doc) {
                InvoiceList.push(doc);
                invoiceAmountTotal = parseFloat(invoiceAmountTotal) + parseFloat(doc.InvoiceAmount);
                 referalCommissionTotal = parseFloat(referalCommissionTotal) + parseFloat(doc.ReferralCommission);
                 developerCommissionTotal= parseFloat(developerCommissionTotal) + parseFloat(doc.DeveloperCommission);
            });
        InvoiceList.sort(SortByID);
        InvoiceList = InvoiceList.slice(pageNo * numberOfRecords, pageNo * numberOfRecords + numberOfRecords);
        // Check the feed and if empty, set the body to 'no docs found', 
        // else take 1st element from feed
        getContext().getResponse().setBody(JSON.stringify({ InvoiceList, count, invoiceAmountTotal, referalCommissionTotal, developerCommissionTotal }));

    });


}
function SortByID(a, b) {
    var aName = a.UpdatedOn.toLowerCase();
    var bName = b.UpdatedOn.toLowerCase();
    return ((aName < bName) ? -1 : ((aName > bName) ? 1 : 0));
}
if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get all 250 back in one shot, you need to populate the options parameter for `queryDocuments()` with a `pageSize` field. It's an optional third parameter for that function call. Without it, this server-side API will default to 100.

You can also set `pageSize` to -1 to get you all documents. However, for server-side stored procedures, I recommend against this. Rather, you need to handle paging using the continuation token. If you want it to be really robust you also need to deal with premature shutdown of the stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks Larry pagesize as -1 is also very helpful.

Comment: The link is now broken, should've brought the code sample in Stack overflow.

Comment: I removed the broken link. It wasn't really necessary for the answer. I also reworded the reference to `pageSize` setting to -1 so that it's no longer in question.